# My bootstrap4 Navbar is not looking correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using bootstrap version 4 and added in a Navbar but it came out looking like this and I am not sure why. I pasted the needed links and double checked however I still can't find the problem. I'm also new to using bootstrap so I would be grateful if anyone can help me.

[A screenshot of how it is looking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0o0y.png)

Here's my code:

This is _document.js

```js
import Document , {Html, Head, Main, NextScript} from 'next/document'

class MyDocument extends Document
{
    render()
    {
        return (
            <Html lang="en">
                <head>
                    <meta name="Online shop" content="Online shop web app" />
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous"></link>
                    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" ></script>
                    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
                    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <Main />
                    <NextScript />

                </body>
            </Html>
        )
    }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

This is Navbar.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link'

const Navbar = () => {
    return (<div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
         <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
        </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        </nav>
  </div>)
}

export default Navbar;
```

I can't find where I went wrong.

Comment: If you check your dev tools, are all files shown as loaded succesfully in network tab?

Comment: Yes, there doesn't seem to be a problem